# join self-reference table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have following self-reference table

```
Name    | Id |CategoryId
--------------------------------
Gruop1  | 1  |null
--------------------------------
Group2  | 2  | 1
--------------------------------
Group3  | 3  | 1
--------------------------------
```

```
Id=int AtuoNumber  
CategoryId=int nullable
```

**I need query that its result is like this** (linq to sql or sql command)

```
Name   | Id | CategoryId  | CategoryName
---------------------------------------------------------
Gruop1 | 1  | null        | null
---------------------------------------------------------
Group2 | 2  | 1           | Group1
 ---------------------------------------------------------
Group3 | 3  | 1           | Group1
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this code but it didn't work properly

```
SELECT *
 FROM   Category e1 
   inner join  Category e2 
   ON e1.Id = e2.CategoryId
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is your definition of not properly?

Comment: @Rob It means It's not the  result I want(it return two category name with with their parent)the question is clear ! I Showed how would be my final result

Comment: I am asking *what is the result of your attempt*. No, it's not clear

Comment: @Rob it's pretty clear, If you had knew the answer you would have posted it, regardless of knowing my query result or not:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are missing the null valued rows (where CategoryId is null). This is because in any RDBMS any comparison to NULL always returns false, even of you compare null to null.

To get what you want, I believe you need a UNION query, with the second part of the union selecting rows where CategoryId  is null

```
SELECT e1.Name , e1.Id , e1.CategoryId, e2.Name as CategoryName
FROM Category AS e1 INNER JOIN Category AS e2 ON e1.id = e2.CategoryId

union 

SELECT e1.Name , e1.Id , e1.CategoryId,null as CategoryName
FROM Category e1  where CategoryId is null
```

Comment: @DarkKnight, your query returns 4 rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e1.name,e1.id,e1.categoryid,e2.name as categoryname
 FROM   Category e1 
   left join  Category e2 
   ON e2.id = e1.CategoryId
```

Comment: Your query is wrong.it won't work properly.it has 4 columns

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you.

declare @temp table
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [CategoryId] [int] NULL ,
    Name varchar(20)
)

---

insert into @temp(CategoryId, Name)
values
(null,'Group1'),
(1,'Group2'),
(1,'Group3')

---

select t1.Name,t1.Id,t1.CategoryId,t2.Name 
from @temp t1
left outer join @temp t2 on t1.CategoryId = t2.Id